# Nesting namespace and missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement an administration panel and I thought it would be nice to have links to different tabs on the left side of the screen and display those tabs on the right side of the screen using AJAX.

I decided to go with `:admin` namespace within my model resources (as I need the `:id`) so I did in **router.rb**:

```
resources :my_model do
    namespace :admin do
        get "panel", to: "panel#index" #The route to display the main admin panel view
        # for now let just assume I have one tab:
        namespace :info_tab do
            get "index", to: "info_tab#index"
        end
    end
end
```

Then in my controllers files I have a hierarchy like this:

`controllers/admin/info_tab/info_tab_controller.rb`

Within this file I wrote (which I am not sure if I did it right)

```
class  Admin::InfoTab::InfoTabController < ApplicationController
    def index
        logger.debug("Index from info_tab_controller loaded!")
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

I implemented the `remote: true` link to this tab and after I click it the method from the controller gets executed, but in my server logs I get this:

```
Started GET "/my_model/1/admin/info_tab/index" for ::1 at 2016-11-10 22:33:55 +0100
Processing by Admin::InfoTab::InfoTabController#index as JS
No template found for Admin::InfoTab::InfoTabController#index, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 69ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

My index view for the `InfoTabController` is places under:

```
views/admin/info_tab/index.js.erb
```

1. What did I do wrong?
2. Is this approach I am trying to do right? Or is there a better way to structure it? (especially the routes)

Answer (score 0):

Rails looks up view paths based on something like

`/app/views/{namespace1}/{namespace2}/{controller}/{action}`

So i would assume you'd need the view path to be

`app/views/admin/info_tab/info_tab/index.*`

Unless you anticipate many different `InfoTab` controllers (like, dozens), I would also recommend removing the `InfoTab` namespace, so your controller is:
`Admin::InfoTabController < ApplicationController` in which case your current view path should just work.

If you want more info on how rails looks up view paths, i'd checkout a blog post like https://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/04/06/digging-rails-how-rails-finds-your-templates-part-4/